# console.log returns an additional undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand .bind and made the following code:

a simply object:

```
person = {
    name:"Joe",
    surname:"Something",
    tool:"gun",
    action: function(){
        console.log("shoot my wife");
    }
}
```

a function:

```
function police(){
    console.log("You are under arrest, " + this.name + " " + this.surname);
}
```

and binding the person object to the police function

```
var newPolice = police.bind(person);
```

And finally I console log it:

```
console.log( newPolice() );
```

I do get the desired string ("You are under arrest, Joe Something") but I also get an undefined and I have no idea where it is coming from. (In the code it is the console.log(newPolice()) that generates the undefined)

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with `bind`.

When you call `newPolice()` it logs the result of this:

> ```
> console.log("You are under arrest, " + this.name + " " + this.surname);
> ```

When you call `console.log( newPolice() );`, you now have **two** `console.log` statements which, between them, log:

- The same thing as before
- The return value of `newPolice`

`newPolice` doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.