# What is undefined in my code?

Tags: javascript, console

JS noob here. I'm running my code in my console and getting my code to return the values I want...but I see and "undefined" message below the returned values. What is my code returning as undefined? Thanks in advance!

Here:

```
function getElementsLessThan100AtProperty(object, key){
var newArray = object[key];
var elementsLessThan100 = [];
var emptyArray =[];
if(newArray.length === 0) {
    return emptyArray;
    } else {
    for(var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++){
        if(newArray[i] < 100){
            elementsLessThan100.push(newArray[i]);
        }
      }return elementsLessThan100;
    }
}

var obj = {
  key: [1000, 20, 50, 500]
};
var output = getElementsLessThan100AtProperty(obj, 'key');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [console.log returns an additional undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974308/console-log-returns-an-additional-undefined)

Comment: Apart from your main question: you don’t need the `length === 0` check and the `emptyArray` at all. The shortest code to achieve what you want is `obj.key.filter(function(value){ return value < 100; });`.

Comment: hi Xufox, thanks for the reply, i was including the length === 0 and empty Array bc it was part of my prompt's question, i'll give this code a shot and let you know what happens

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` is the return value of `console.log`