# Usage of rest parameter with object

Tags: ecmascript-6, parameter-passing

I am trying to pull the user information by passing some object values as rest parameter. Whenever I try to pass 2 arguments, the code throws an error (undefined). What is it that I am missing?

Here is the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/StammeringMan/6ezjov25/26/) link of what I am trying to do.

```js
let userAddress = [{
  "street": "someStreet1",
  "house": "1",
  "person": "User1"
}, {
  "street": "someStreet2",
  "house": "2",
  "person": "User2"
}, {
  "street": "someStreet3",
  "house": "3",
  "person": "User3"
}];

let userInfo = [];

let addressToCheck = (...newUserHouse) => {
  for (let address of userAddress) {
    if (newUserHouse == address.house) {
      userInfo.push(address.person);
      console.log(userInfo);
    }
  }
}

console.log(addressToCheck(3, 2));
```

---

**EDIT**

**Additional info:**

I had this problem in which I had a JSON data and I had to pass multiple values and check whether those values were present in the dataset or not and if present, display the whole object.

For example; In the `userAddress` Array (as shown above) I need to check if `3`, `2` (passed as an argument) are present as `house` number in `userAddress`. If they are present, then display the whole information about that particular object. As in this case, since `3`, `2` are valid house numbers, the expected result should be:

```
Object { "street": "someStreet2", "house": "2", "person": "User2" }  
Object { "street": "someStreet3", "house": "3", "person": "User3" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A functional way to achieve this using ES6 is to utilize the Array's [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) methods in a custom function, (namely `getUsersMatchingHouseNumbers`), as shown in the gist below:

```js
const userData = [{
  "street": "someStreet1",
  "house": 1,
  "person": "User1"
}, {
  "street": "someStreet2",
  "house": 2,
  "person": "User2"
}, {
  "street": "someStreet3",
  "house": 3,
  "person": "User3"
}]


function getUsersMatchingHouseNumbers(userData, ...houseNumbers) {
  return userData.filter(({ house }) => houseNumbers.includes(house));
}

console.log(getUsersMatchingHouseNumbers(userData, 1, 3));
```

**Notes**

1. The `userData.filter(({ house })` part uses [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to obtain only the `house` property/value from each `userData` object.
2. The `getUsersMatchingHouseNumbers` function returns an array of user objects whose `house` number matches those passed to the function when it is invoked.

Comment: It seems more logical than running two different loops. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The code does not throw an `undefined` error, it simply *logs* the value `undefined`. And that happens because you are calling `console.log` on the return value of `addressToCheck` but the function doesn't return a value, so it implicitly returns `undefined`. See [console.log returns an additional undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974308/console-log-returns-an-additional-undefined).

---

However, there are more problems with your code. It only accidentally works when you pass a single argument because you are using loose comparison (`==`).

The value of a rest parameter is always an **array**. That means you are really doing the following comparisons:

```
[1, 2] == "1"
[1, 2] == "2"
[1, 2] == "3"
```

I hope it's obvious why this cannot work. An array with multiple elements cannot be equal to a single "element", so the `if` condition is never fulfilled.

It works accidentally with a single argument because the string representation of `[1]` is simply `"1"`. The string representation if `[1,2]` however is `"1,2"`.

You are not explaining what the desired outcome is but if you want to select all addresses for the provided input, you should be using `.filter` instead. And you can convert the provided arguments to a set for fast lookup.

Instead of assigning values to an "external" array, simply return the result from the function.

```js
let userAddress = [{
  "street": "someStreet1",
  "house": "1",
  "person": "User1"
}, {
  "street": "someStreet2",
  "house": "2",
  "person": "User2"
}, {
  "street": "someStreet3",
  "house": "3",
  "person": "User3"
}];

let addressToCheck = (...newUserHouse) => {
  newUserHouse = new Set(newUserHouse);
  return userAddress.filter(address => newUserHouse.has(address.house));
};

console.log(addressToCheck("3", "2"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Actually, I want to pass multiple "house value" and check if the house value is present in the object.

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I was missing out the point that rest parameters are an **array of parameters** and in order to manipulate them, we have to iterate over them too.

```js
let userAddress = [{
  "street": "someStreet1",
  "house": 1,
  "person": "User1"
}, {
  "street": "someStreet2",
  "house": 2,
  "person": "User2"
}, {
  "street": "someStreet3",
  "house": 3,
  "person": "User3"
}]


let addressToCheck = (...houses) => {
 for(let house of houses){
   for (let user of userAddress) {
     if(user.house === house){
       console.log(user);
        break;
      }
   }
  }
}

console.log(addressToCheck(1, 3));
```